# Translate makefile to produce static libxxx.a instead of dynamic libxxx.dylib

Tags: macos, makefile, compilation, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I am compiling a library (http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar) but issuing "make" with its included makefile on my mac produces a dynamic library (.dylib). I would much rather have a static library so that I can deploy it with my app. Is it easy/possible to translate the flags in the makefile to produce a static library?

It seems that "make" is just compiling and linking some C/C++ code.

Comment: This is why I wish people would just use automake and libtool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's building the objects with any dylib-specific compilation flags, so you could just do the library build manually with something like:

```
make && ar cru libAntTweakBar.a && ranlib libAntTweakBar.a
```

Comment: This was more or less the solution, though linking to the static library I created was a bit tricky. Here's my final solution for this particular library: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1370

Answer (score 1):

I have bad news for you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x) probably prevents you from doing what you want.

Comment: Just because @mangledorf can't build a completely static binary doesn't mean he's unable to build a static library.