# ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o on OSX 10.6 with gcc/clang -static flag

Tags: macos, gcc, ld

When I try to build the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

On OS X 10.6.4, with the following flags:

```
gcc -static -o blah blah.c
```

It returns this:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Has anyone else encountered this, or is it something that noone else has been affected with yet?  Any fixes?

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to static link on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x)

Answer (score 98):

This won’t work. From the `man` page for `gcc`:

> This option will not work on Mac OS X unless all libraries (including libgcc.a) have also been compiled with -static.  Since neither a static version of libSystem.dylib nor crt0.o are provided, this option is not useful to most people.

Comment: Thanks. It's useful to me purely because I'm interested in reverse engineering :P

Comment: @browneye - were you able to figure out how to reverse engineer on mac without static???

Answer (score 6):

Per Nate's answer, a completely static application is apparently not possible - see also **man ld**:

> **-static** Produces a mach-o file that does not use the dyld.  Only used building the kernel.

The problem in linking with static libraries is that, if both a static and a dynamic version of a library are found in the same directory, the dynamic version will be taken in preference. Three ways of avoiding this are:

1. Do not attempt to find them via the -L and -l options; instead, specify the full paths, to the libraries you want to use, on the compiler or linker command line.

   > $ g++ -Wall -Werror -o hi **/usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a** hi.cpp
2. Create a separate directory, containing symbolic links to the static libraries, use the -L option to have this directory searched first, and use the -l option to specify the libraries you want to use.

   > $ g++ -Wall -Werror **-L ./staticBoostLib -l boost_unit_test_framework** -o hi hi.cpp
3. Instead of creating a link of the same name in a different directory, create a link of a different name in the same directory, and specify that name in a -l argument.

   > $ g++ -Wall -Werror **-l boost_unit_test_framework_static** -o hi hi.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You may also try LLVM LLD linker - I did prebuilt version for my two major OSes - https://github.com/VerKnowSys/Sofin-llds

This one allows me to link for exmple: "Qemu" properly - which is impossible with ld preinstalled by Apple.

And last one is - to build GCC yourself with libstdc++ (don't).

Comment: Also worth mention - it might require LLVM 3.9 itself with compiled-in libc++ - to support "-static -lc++" passed to linker.