# Static -libgfortran in library build

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran, static-linking

I am trying to build a library that only has static references to `libgfortran` (and preferably `libgcc` also).

However, if I use the linker flags

```
-static -lgfortran -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc
```

on OS X I get

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and if I try to use

```
-shared -lgfortran -static-libgfortran
```

I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_quadmath_snprintf", referenced from:
      _write_float in libgfortran.a(write.o)
  "_strtoflt128", referenced from:
      __gfortrani_convert_real in libgfortran.a(read.o)
      __gfortrani_convert_infnan in libgfortran.a(read.o)
```

and everything compiles fine (but has a dynamic link to libgfortran and libgcc) if I use `-dynamiclib -lgfortran`.

It would appear that [gcc is not build statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801011) on OS X.

**How do I build my library so that end-users don't need to have gfortran or gcc installed?**

I'm using the macports version of gcc but I'm prepared to use another distributor of gfortran/gcc if it allows me to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
-dynamiclib -lgfortran -static-libgfortran \
  /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libquadmath.a -static-libgcc
```

seems to do the trick!

The bizarre thing was figuring out that I needed to add a full path to the `libquadmath.a`, which feels like a bug with `gcc`/`gfortran` to be honest.

Comment: Based on your solution, i ended up with this one: `-l:libgfortran.a -l:libquadmath.a` .  I did not need static libgcc so did not try that part.