# haskell makefile import library

Tags: haskell, makefile, ghc

So I have the following makefile which I want to use to compile my haskell program. However, in my `program.hs` file I have imported a library that is not in the standard Haskell distribution (e.g. `Data.List`). As a result, when I try to compile I get the error below. How can I include the said library so that it compiles fine? P.S. I am **NOT** interested in other approaches which do not involve a makefile, thank you.

error:

```
Linking program...
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

makefile:

```
 program: program.hs
        ghc --make -static -optl-static program.hs
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (this includes the .hs file).

Comment: `crt0` is a C library, not a Haskell one. Something is going wrong, and it does not depend on Haskell libraries. I wonder if your `clang` can produce static executables from C sources (?)

Comment: @chi thx for the answer, I dont know anything about c, but I was getting `gcc failed in phase Linker. (Exit code: 1) makefile:2: recipe for target 'program' failed make: ***[program] Error 1` without the 2 static options and adding them fixed it

Comment: As you seem to have anticipated, the reasonable answer is: _don't use `make` to build Haskell projects, use `cabal` or `stack` instead_. Make, especially GNU Make, is bogged down not only with anachronistic environment assumptions but also ridiculous implicit rules for languages nobody has been using for 30 years anymore. (Well, not literally _nobody_, and of course you can and should just turn those off, but still...) If it matters because you don't have root permissions and only GHC installed, note that `stack` can be installed entirely in user space.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Of course `cabal` can be installed entirely in user space, too (and that is the default behavior of `bootstrap.sh`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You went down the wrong path with static options. I assume you're on os-x. As explained at [ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o on OSX 10.6 with gcc/clang -static flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801011/ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt0-o-on-osx-10-6-with-gcc-clang-static-flag) that just makes things worse. In fact you got a different error, because you got an *earlier* error.

To write a good makefile, first ensure you can run ghc to compile the program *without* make, just by running the commands in the shell.

I.e. try to compile just `ghc --make program.hs` and see what happens. If you have the other libraries in your package environment already, it doesn't matter if they're in the standard distribution or not.