# What is the proper way to build for macOS-x86_64 using cmake on Apple M1 (arm)?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, cross-compiling, apple-silicon

I'm using a library that I cannot compile for Apple M1, so I have decided to compile it and use it using (Rosetta 2) for x86_64 which I successfully did following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67418208/1163561) to install brew and clang for x86_64.

However when I compile my project and try to link it against this library I get this error:

```sh
ld: warning: ignoring file ..../libapronxx.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I have tried to the set compiler and linker flags ("-arch x86_64") but still got the same problem.

My question is: What is the proper way to build for macOS-x86_64 using cmake on Apple M1 (arm)?

Additional information: I'm using cmake via CLion.

UPDATE:
I successfully compiled my project using the following commands:

```sh
# install a x86 cmake
arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install cmake
...
# in the build directory
arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/cmake ..
make
arch -x86_64 ./my_exe
```

I also specified the architecture for clang using -arch flag

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE " -arch x86_64 -O3")
string(APPEND CMAKE_CC_FLAGS_RELEASE " -arch x86_64 -O3")
# did the same for debug too
```

While this work fine, I still don't believe it is the proper way to use cmake to build for macOS-x86_64, in fact I cannot take the advantages of my IDE with all this manual approach.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I can successfully compile the library and use with its own test files (the library uses a MakeFile), what I'm hoping to get from this question is a recommended approach to compile for macOS-x86_64 from an apple ARM machine regardless of what I did wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I incorrectly interpreted your question. After re-reading the error message the things becomes clear.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After checking CMake source code, I found that it is enough to set `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` to `x86_64`:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "x86_64")
```

This is the cleanest way so far to solve this issue, and work straight forward with CLion too.

Comment: I did not get this to work properly, and needed to do this `set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "x86_64" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)`

Comment: What is "set(...)" - is that run from the command line or put somewhere else ?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, `set(...)` is a CMake command to be put at the beginning of your `CMakeLists.txt` file.