# Installing OpenMP on Mac with M1Pro

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, openmp, apple-m1

I followed the instructions here: [Using x86 libraries and OpenMP on macOS arm64 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386941/using-x86-libraries-and-openmp-on-macos-arm64-architecture/67418208#67418208)

I am trying to compile simple code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n",
               omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

using:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 main.cpp
```

but I am getting error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.0_2/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/omp.h:18:
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:93:15: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

Can anyone help me with next steps? I suppose I should add stdlib somewhere, but I don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: 1. every C compiler should find `stdlib.h` without any help from you. 2. I don't have an M1, but: why are you installing x86 stuff? Is there no native compiler available? If there is, OpenMP should be included in any C/C++/Fortran compiler.

Comment: 1. That's my question why it is not included. 2. Generally, OpenMp is not supported on M1 Mac