# ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o

Tags: macos, go, cgo

/Users/***/code/go/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
how to install crt0.o in macos?

Comment: What's your code ? What's your project? It's difficult to solve your problem without more detail. BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801011/ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt0-o-on-osx-10-6-with-gcc-clang-static-flag this Q may cover your desciption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o on OSX 10.6 with gcc/clang -static flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801011/ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt0-o-on-osx-10-6-with-gcc-clang-static-flag)