# How / is it possible to build C "Hello world" program entirely static (OS X, Clang)?

Tags: clang, static-linking

Is it possible to compile C "Hello world" program to have final executable entirely static?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
clang -static main.c
```

But it gives:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've seen [staticly linked libc?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Feb/msg00699.html) but I want to get additional information on this topic.

P.S. I am asking this for education purposes rather than for real practice.

Comment: After running `clang`, what's the output of `ldd a.out` ?

Comment: @RichardFearn, sorry! It was the wrong copy/paste. It is just clang produces this message.

Comment: I've found duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259249/creating-static-mac-os-x-c-build

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x

Comment: Anyway, Google didn't reveal them for me when I searched so I think it is OK to keep my question here on SO as well.