# How to make a static link with libpython in "OS X Framework-build python"

Tags: python, c++, macos, gcc, g++

I am trying to make a static link with `libpython2.7` on `Mac OS X 10.11`.

While static-linking successfully worked with `libpython2.7.a` in `pyenv(anaconda)-build python`, it didn't work with `libpython2.7.a` in `Framework-build python`.

[Creating static Mac OS X C build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259249/creating-static-mac-os-x-c-build)

Since it seems `-static` option does NOT work on Mac OS X,
I tried the following.

```
CXXFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
LIBS=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a

$ g++ -o main main.cc $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

and got the following result.

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.10)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Linking with `libpython2.7.a` resulted in dynamic-linking with `Versions/2.7/Python`.

I also found that both of `libpython2.7.a` and `libpython2.7.dylib` are the symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python`.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
-> ../../../Python

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
-> ../../../Python
```

1. Why there exists no valid static library for `libpython2.7` in `Framework-build python` ?
2. What's the difference between `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` and a standard shared library?
3. How can I make a static link with `libpython2.7` in `Framework-build python` ?