# Standalone ImageMagick for mac

Tags: macos, imagemagick

So I've been struggling with this for quite some time now. I can't get ImageMagick to compile for Mac so that I can package it in my application. The paths are always absolute and not relative.

Has anyone compiled it for use as a package in their own app?

Thanks.

Comment: It compiles but when I copy that compilation to another system it shows paths from the system it was compiled from

Comment: Please show an example; also there's pre-compiled binaries on the ImageMagick site, why not use that instead? ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0.tar.gz

Comment: the precompiled binaries don't run standalone. I get this error when I try to run the convert command from the bin folder.

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Zohaib/Desktop/ImageMagick-7.0.3/bin/./convert
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Compiling from source should work though, as I just compiled it without installing and it ran fine. You still haven't provided the information on the "absolute" paths your refer too...

Comment: So jpg/png are working fine. When we want to add exr support the paths for the shared libraries are not fixed. It tries to fetch them from /Users/Zohaib/.. rather than a relative path after which I should be able to use it on any system.

Comment: In that case build it statically... that way you aren't dependent upon those shared libs.

Comment: Tried that too.. Only getting issues with exr

Comment: Did you download the `exr` delegate for it separately and also build it statically? I'm pretty sure you'll have to do this for anything that is not automatically included and has a value of `no` showing after compiling.

Comment: Yeah we downloaded the exr delegate separately. Png/Jpg works fine and the paths are relative. Really have no clue what's wrong with exr.

Comment: @I'L'I I don't believe you can compile statically and distribute on OSX http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259427/2836621