# error while statically building Haskell code

Tags: c, haskell

I have tried to build my code dynamically and it worked as expected, however when I try to statically build with the option `--ghc-options '-optl-static -fPIC'` I got the follow error

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see   invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

any idea?

edit : I added the c tag since I though the gcc is somehow related to c and I guess the error related to c library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating static Mac OS X C build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259249/creating-static-mac-os-x-c-build)

Comment: I have checked, while am trying to build the same on linux and got the same error, the thread states that the problem was with Mac OS X while am getting the same with linux also