# Avoid linking in unused symbols when linking against static libs

Tags: c++, linker, darwin

I'm using the [apple gcc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/) to compile a dylib that I'm going to redistribute. For various reasons I'm using some libraries, let's say `libz` to keep it simple.

Since this library is not typically found on a Mac system I wish to [static link in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x) used symbols into the dylib by passing the path to the `.a-file` to simplify deployment.

Now, the linker links in *all* symbols from the lib into the resulting dylib although I only reference a subset. On linux I've never encountered this problem, the linker happily discards all unreferenced symbols and creates a very slim executable, so it should be *possible*. The dylib file I have now is ~10 times larger than it should.

I've tried fiddle around with the -dead_code linker flag, but to no avail. Perhaps I just don't understand it?

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Try `-Wl,--gc-sections`](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/removing-unused-functionsdead-codes-with-gccgnu-ld/).

As regards [`-dead_strip`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-622.5.1/RelNotes/CompilerTools.html?txt) (what you probably meant by `-dead_code`):

> Before turning on the -dead_strip
>   option your project will first have to
>   be "ported" to work with dead code
>   stripping. This will include changing
>   from -gused (the default for -g) to
>   -gfull and re-compiling all of the objects files being linked into your
>   program with the new compiler from the
>   Mac OS X June 2004 release. Also if
>   your building an executable that loads
>   plugins, which uses symbols from the
>   executable, you will have to make sure
>   the symbols the plugins use are not
>   stripped (by using
>   **attribute**((used)) or the -exported_symbols_list option). If you are using an export list and building
>   a shared library, or an executable
>   that will be used with ld(1)'s
>   -bundle_loader flag, you need to include the symbols for exception
>   frame information in the export list
>   for your exported C++ symbols. These
>   symbols end with .eh and can be seen
>   with the nm(1) tool.

[and](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/CodeFootprint/Articles/CompilerOptions.html):

> To enable dead-code stripping from the
>   command line, pass the -dead_strip
>   option to ld. You should also pass the
>   -gfull option to GCC to generate a complete set of debugging symbols for
>   your code. The linker uses this extra
>   debugging information to dead strip
>   the executable.

Hope this helps.

<sup>All content in this answer was located within the first few Google search results for "apple ld static link unused symbols". :)</sup>

Comment: thanks for googleing this up. Compiling on mac yeilds "Mach-O" objects as opposed to ELF which I beleive are used with the `--gc-sections` switch. I tried the `-gfull` switch together with the `-dead_strip` but to no avail.