# How to tell qmake to use static libraries if both dynamic and static versions exist?

Tags: c++, linker, qmake

I have both static and dynamic versions of Boost installed in `/usr/local/lib`, i.e. both `libboost_system.dylib` and `libboost_system.a` exist.

In my qmake project file I've added the Boost libraries to the linker like so: `LIBS += -lboost_system`

Can I tell qmake to prefer the static versions without explicitly stating the filename, so that I can reduce the amount of qmake code to get static linking on all platforms?

Comment: If I understood your question correct, you can find answer here http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/?title=Building_static_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not really possible, and specifying absolute paths to libraries is a much better solution (i.e. how CMake does it by default).

Comment: But this doesn't handle static dependencies nicely. For example, Boost might depend on zlib but it is not pulled in automatically. This is especially a problem for mingw.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `qmake`, but there is a way to make gcc link to a static lib by put `-static` flags to linker. All libs that you want to link statically should put after this flag.

I searched for `qmake`'s document, and found that you can modify the link flags by change the variable `QMAKE_LFLAGS`, or may directly add this flag to `LIBS`

Comment: I did try that but encountered the same problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x Also that would seem to imply that there is no way to prefer static libraries without simply specifying the full filename. I'll leave this open for a while so someone can confirm either way.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156055/gcc-static-linking-only-some-libraries, so try `LIBS += -static -lsomelib --Wl,-Bdynamic`?