# statically linked libraries on mac

Tags: c, macos, linker, static-linking

I just don't understand.

I'm to believe that gcc automatically links libc.a when invoking the gcc driver.

However, out of curiosity I wanted to link libc.a statically using `-static`, but I get;

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just don't understand? Also, whats `crt0`?

I've also read posts saying to **never** statically link libc.a ; why? From what I've read (admittedly I'm just an undergrad), I don't see the drawbacks in linking statically..

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x) post which told me to add `-lc` which seems to compile correctly, but is this statically linking or just adding libc.dylib ?

Additionally, anytime I use `-static` flag, I get the same error returned from `ld`. I don't understand? The text I'm working through shows examples using a Unix environment, and since OS X is Unix-based, why am I having so many difficulties with my Mac?

Thanks, Zak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of Apple's decisions about how libraries and development should work. They dissuade you from building static binaries by making it as difficult as possible.

There's some weak-sauce explanation available here on [http://developer.apple.com/](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1118/_index.html), the useful tidbit is:

```
>     If your project absolutely must create a statically linked binary, 
> you can get the Csu (C startup) module from [Darwin][2] and try
> building crt0.o for yourself. Obviously, we won't support such an
> endeavor.
```

If you feel like you're swimming upstream, get used to it - because it won't get any easier with app sandboxing, signing, dyld changes, etc etc.

On the plus side, trying to do unix stuff on OSX is edgy and dangerous now.

A couple useful links for down the road:

http://reverse.put.as/2013/03/20/how-to-compile-gdb-in-mountain-lion-updated/
http://www.osxbook.com/

Comment: Why would creating a statically linked binary be dangerous, as they elude to in the apple docs?

Comment: Creating a statically linked binary isn't dangerous - Apple's "argument" seems to be 'Things change so often that you should really use the shared libs so that API changes down the line don't break your code.' It's a reasonable argument - it's the amount of effort they put into blocking you from doing it (and other things) that is annoying. And, don't get me wrong, two mac pro desktops and a macpro laptop here - I love me some brushed metal unix. But, making that commitment means a lot of extra effort that you wouldn't have to undergo if you used Linux.

Comment: How would changed in the API affect a statically linked binary? I don't understand. The whole point of statically linking is that it produces a fully-loadable/executable binary?

Comment: A historical example I can think of off the top of my head - back in 10.4 you used to be able to run mach_inject into any mach process without any special privileges because you could sysctl enable  KERN_TFP_POLICY_PERMISSIVE. In 10.5 they removed that option. So if you had some static code that expected that capability - you'd be out of luck. This type of thing happens all the time. If you're doing super-generic UNIX stuff, yah, static binary should last you a while. But if a new OSX version comes out and your thing breaks don't act suprised.

Comment: hmm. I'll need to do some more reading, but thank you for your responses! very helpful!

Comment: An even more likely scenario: a security bug is found in an OS-supplied library and fixed in an OS X software update. If your executable is dynamically linked, no problem.  If it were statically linked, your application remains vulnerable to the security problem. If your application has been downloaded by many, multiply the problem.