# Ocaml / ReasonML - Missing libraries in built executable

Tags: ocaml, reason, ocaml-dune

I have an ReasonML project that is using `dune build` to build an executable. The executable runs on the development machine (where the code is built) without any problems. However, if I copy this exe to my other laptop (Another mac with the same OSX version), I can´t execute the file due to missing libraries:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/foo
  Reason: image not found
```

I´m not very experienced with ocaml / reason but I expected the executable to bundle all necessary dependencies within the binary.

Is there a special build-flag or some other step that I have to perform apart from `dune build` in order to include all necessary libs?

Comment: If you are building a backend service, remember that you would typically Dockerize it to deploy it. So library linking becomes a non-issue. If you're building a CLI to distribute to users, then yeah you need to solve the linking problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is statically linking binaries. MacOS unfortunately does not official encourage or recommend static linking. An old page can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html).  You might find [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718406/statically-linked-libraries-on-mac) useful as well.

This has less to do with OCaml itself and more wrt how linkers behave on different platforms (MacOS, Linux etc)

To overcome your issue, you could checkout [esy-gmp](https://github.com/esy-packages/esy-gmp) assuming you are using [esy](https://esy.sh/) as your package manager. If you're on OPAM, you could add [conf-gmp](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/conf-gmp/conf-gmp.1/) to you opam dependencies

All this being said, if you're interested in static linking on supported platform like Linux (and Windows too I guess?), you'll have to provide C linker flags via dune

```lisp
(link_flags (-ccopt -static))
```