# How to use gcc command with '-static'

Tags: c, gcc, static-linking

When I tried to use gcc command to compile a test program with a static library 't1' which archive by myself.

The command I use to archive static library like this:

```
ar rcv libt1.a t1.o
```

Use the following command got An error:

```
gcc -L. -static -lt1 t.c -o t

ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But, If I remove '-static' like this:

```
gcc -L. -lt1 t.c -o t
```

It compile successfully. And I got the right result.

But I search a lot, find out other guys use '-static', and they do not get an error. So, please help me figure that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x

Comment: `-static` is not needed to link against static libraries, but to link statically against the C/C++ runtime libraries, which AFAICT is not what you are trying to achieve; you can do without it. By the way, why are you putting a `.c` file into a static library?

Comment: @MatteoItalia  that's a write mistake, what I mean is "t1.o".

Comment: the `gcc` linker retrieves/processes command line arguments left to right, So I am surprised that either method worked.  I.E. the `-L` and `-l` should be at the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comment, `-static` is not required to link against a static library of yours, but is used to instruct the compiler to link statically against the C (and C++, in case of g++) runtime libraries. This [is not supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html) on OS X (link taken from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x) above), hence the error.

To link against your static library, just do as you did in the second command line, without specifying `-static`.

> But I search a lot, find out other guys use '-static', and they do not get an error. So, please help me figure that.

They are probably working on Linux or Windows, where static linking against libc is supported (although even on Linux it brings its fair share of problems).

Answer (score 1):

> ar rcv libt1.a t1.c

Typo? You don't normally want a C source file in a library.....

Clang is known to be a bit picky, especially with static libraries (Is this on MacOS, by any chance?) and will try and link to a non-existing runtime library - You can work around this by handing over the static library as an *object file* instead of a *library* like

```
gcc t.o libt1.a -o t
```

This should work.

Comment: It's a write mistake, what I mean is "t1.o", and I truly work on MacOS.The command you give is work as well, but I am just curious why the '-static' make an error.