# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Compile Failure. Quit

Tags: c, macos, gcc

`/usr/bin/gcc -DEVAL -std=c11 -O2 -pipe -static -s -o Tutorial Tutorial.c -lm`

this command line (right on linux) don't run on macOS, 
How can i change this command line?
UPDATE: the command line that doesn't work is

`gcc -DEVAL -static -std=c11 -O2 -pipe -s -o main.out $1 -lm -g`

Comment: What command does not run? Try `gcc` instead of `/usr/bin/gcc` since on MacOSX the GCC compiler might be somewhere else

Comment: Note that `gcc` resolves to `clang` on os x.

Comment: It is the `-static` causing the issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x